# Could not find module 'RxSwift'

Tags: swift, xcode, rx-swift

I imported BitcoinKit.swift which worked fine but get now the error:

```
Could not find module 'RxSwift' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator
```

## Podfile:

```rb
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '15.2'

target 'BTCTransaction5' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'BitcoinKit.swift'

end
```

## System

macOS Big Sur

M1

Thanks for Help!

Comment: Hello, could you try a build on "Any iOS device" ? Your code compiles on a real device ? 
I think it's due to `"EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]": "arm64"` in the `pod spec` of `BitcoinKit.swift` pod

Comment: Thanks, but im getting now a new error. Error: "The linked framework "Pods_....framework" is missing one or more architectures required by this traget: i386. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I just needed to exclude some architectures and it worked :)
Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed it by excluding some architectures in the Build Settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update the pod with this?

```
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn´t worked. I fixed it by excluding some architectures.